# Not able to Add module in Android studio project, sync option also not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gitignore

I'm not able to see any sync button in my studio, also not able to add module(aar, jar) , there is red X mark over run option on APP and ProjectName( eg. "Helloword")
i tried to add facets but it says No Suitable modules for Anroid facets found.
i also tried to add modules from Dependencies option but it says Found no module to depend upon.
i have diff branches in my git repo and sync the projects from there so same project for diffrent branch is working fine but when i open this perticular version it just doesnt work.
another thing i have nothing inside gradle.setting - is this problem ? if yes what should be there in this file.
i have added gitignore file for

```
            *.iml
           .gradle
           build
           /*/build
           /.idea/workspace.xml
           /.idea/libraries
           /local.properties
           /captures
```

It asks me that no .iml files found , for eg . if a have added abc.aar or abcd.jar then there should be abc.iml and abcd.iml.
not able to understand this,

Any help is appreciated , Thanks for any help.

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: go to File. Select the option Invalidate Cache/Restart and select the same option again in popup. It will fix.

Comment: clean and rebuild many times but not working, 
i did cache/Restart several times does not work @ Janki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Related to Proxy setting in the network..
connected open network , invalidate and restart project,
and this works fine